# Running a script in a screen at start up

Tags: init.d, gnu-screen

I have a Python script that I wish to keep running all the time on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine, and I am doing so by adding an init job that runs a short script that checks for a screen session and if not present creates one.

**/etc/init.d/my-script**:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

case "$1" in
  start)
    /usr/local/bin/start.sh
    ;;
  stop|restart|force-reload)
    ;;
  *)
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

**/usr/local/bin/start.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

SCREEN_NAME="my-script"
INVOCATION="./my-script.py"

# Make sure we are in the working directory.
cd /usr/local/bin

if ! screen -list | grep -q "${SCREEN_NAME}"; then
    screen -dmS "${SCREEN_NAME}" "${INVOCATION}"
fi
```

The problem is that the screen is not being created when I run `/etc/init.d/my-script start`. It runs fine when I execute `./start.sh` and when I debugged it, it definitely executes the screen statement inside the if statement, and the exit code from screen is 0.

So why doesn't it create the screen?

Comment: I switched to using `cron` to run `start.sh` every half hour but I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that there's a failure running your `my-script.py` script, rather than a problem with `screen`. I see that you're referencing it from the current directory - which may not be the current directory when running from init and/or cron.

Can you try using the full path to the script in the `INVOCATION` variable?